# What happens when identical keys are passed to the Mapper in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

What is the significance of data being passed as key/value pairs to the mapper also in the Hadoop Map Reduce framework. I understand that key/value pairs hold significance when they are passed to the reducers as they cater to the partitioning of data coming from the mappers. Values belonging to the same key go as a list from the mapper to the reducer stage. But how are the keys used before the mapper stage itself? What happens to values belonging to the same key? If we don't define a custom input format, I presume Hadoop takes in the record number from the input file as the key and the text line as the value in the mapper function. But in case we decide to implement a custom input format there is a custom selection of the keys and there could be a possibility where we have values corresponding to the same key.

How does phenomenon get handled in the mapper stage? Does the mapper ignore duplicate records and treats them as separate records or does it only choose one record per key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An input split is a chunk of the input that is processed by a
single map. Each map processes a single split. Each split is divided into records, and
the map processes each record—a key-value pair—in turn.

So mapper treats records with same key as separate records.

Comment: That would hold true in case of the default input format where different chunks will have their individual record numbers and since the record numbers are the keys, they would be unique for each mapper. But what would happen in case of a custom input format where the record number is not the key?

Comment: @Abhishek Mapper will process each key-value pair separately. Every key-value pair produced by RecordReader will be processed by user define map method in mapper class independently. Mapper will emit new key-value pair. And all the same keys emitted by mapper will be reduced in a single reducer.

Comment: I agree. But what is the significance of reading key value pairs in the map? We could just have one entity instead of 2 entities. Have the full record sent to the map as a single entity. Why break it into key value pairs at the time of input to the map. For the reducer I understand the significance but for the mapper input, it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: It is certainly the case that the Key can be useful in the Mapper - consider the case where you want to filter records that are NOT key X. So why not merge the Key into the Value as a field instead of having them separate? Because both the Key and the Value in MapReduce can be ANY Writable - so in many cases there might not be any sensible way to combine them into a single Writable type. As you have yourself experienced, there are cases in which there is no useful logical key or the logical key is part of the value, in which case the Key to the Map can be ignored.

Comment: @AlexA.         I agree that the key could be useful in filtering records.

Comment: @Abhishek Have a look at following link. May help u... http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/09/why-does-hadoop-uses-kv-keyvalue-pairs.html